# Python - zfill padding elements with leading Zeros

Tags: python, element, padding, leading-zero

I have the following values:

```
sample = ['934254','10031331','331568','10257969','857042','10278189','10275615','10254453']
```

When I run the below, I get the same output as the original values, the padding of leading zeros does not take place. Please can you advise. Thanks.

```
res = str(sample).zfill(8)
print(res)
```

The output should be:

```
00934254, 10031331, 00331568, etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is turning sample into a string representation of the list then using `zfill` on it.

You need to apply the `zfill` to all the elements. Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this.

```
res = [s.zfill(8) for s in sample]
```